# Should I use Redux, Context, or hooks? And how to implement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm stuck on the problem of passing my state to functions outside of a class. I'm new to coding in general but I'm pretty sure I need to use either hooks, context, or Redux to complete this. First let me post my code.

```js
    class Counter extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 10,
      ran: "",
      id: "",
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1),
      draw: {
        score: 0
      },
      user: {
        score: 0,
        choice: ""
      },
      pc: {
        score: 0,
        choice: ""
      },
      roundLimit: 10,
      roundWinner: ""
    };

        this.setWinner = this.setWinner.bind(this);
        this.setWeapon = this.setWeapon.bind(this);
        this.battle = this.battle.bind(this);
        this.attack = this.attack.bind(this);
      }

      setWeapon = (pcId, userId) => {

        const [ pcWeaponName, userWeaponName] = [pcId, userId].map(weaponId => weapons.find(w => w.weaponId === weaponId).name);

        console.log(this.state.pc.choice, pcWeaponName)

        this.setState({
          user: { score: this.state.user.score, choice: userWeaponName },
          pc: { score: this.state.pc.score, choice: pcWeaponName }
        });
      };

      setWinner = (winner = "draw") => {
        const { score, choice } = this.state[winner];

        const newScore = score + 1;

        this.setState({
          roundWinner: winner,
          [winner]: { score: newScore, choice }
        });
      };

      battle = userWeaponId => {
        //Get PC Choice
        const generatePcWeapon = () =>
          [...weapons][Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];

        const pcWeapon = generatePcWeapon();
        const { weaponId: pcWeaponId, weaknesses = [] } = pcWeapon;
        // Get User Choice

        // Compare IDs
        if (pcWeaponId === userWeaponId) {
          // Update roundWinner to Draw
          this.setWinner();
          // Return
          return;
        }

        // Search for user choice in PC Weaknesses

        this.setWeapon(pcWeaponId, userWeaponId);

        const winner = weaknesses.includes(userWeaponId) ? "user" : "pc";

        this.setWinner(winner);
      };

      attack = id => {
        this.battle(id); // your alert function
      };

      render(props) {
        const { user, pc, roundWinner } = this.state;
        return (
          <>
            <div className="container">
              <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                  <Col>
                    <h5>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h5>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col>
                    <h6> Select Your Weapon </h6>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                {weapons.map(({ name, weaponId }) => {
                  return (
                    <Row key={weaponId}>
                      <Col>
                        <WeaponButton
                          attackAction={this.attack}
                          id={weaponId}
                          name={name}
                        />
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  );
                })}{" "}
              </Container>
            </div>

            <ReactInfo
              id={user.choice}
              ran={pc.choice}
              roundWinner={roundWinner}
              userPoint={user.score}
              pcPoint={pc.score}
            />
          </>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Counter;
```

That is my counter class. These are the alert functionality I am trying to use the states from the class for:

```js
    const ScoreRecord = () => {
      const { userPoint, pcPoint } = this.props;
      return (

        <p>
          The score is You:{userPoint} to PC:{pcPoint}
        </p>
      );
    };

    export function doAlert ({ props }) {
      const { roundWinner, userPoint, pcPoint } = props;
      const isSuccess = roundWinner === "User";
      const message = isSuccess ? "You won dude." : "Youre fucking lame";
      const title = isSuccess ? "Winner" : "Boo";

      const DoAlert = (<AlertComponent isSuccess={isSuccess} message={message} title={title}>
          <ScoreRecord userPoint={userPoint} pcPoint={pcPoint} />
        </AlertComponent>
      );
    export function AlertMessageForm ({ children, isSuccess, message, title, scores }) {

      return (
        <Alert variant={isSuccess ? "success" : "info"} dismissible>
          <Alert.Heading>{title}!</Alert.Heading>
          <p>{message}</p>
          <hr />
          {children}
        </Alert>
      );
    };
```

And here is the codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-bush-0bn77?file=/src/Alert/Alert.js:70-351)

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I have checked the sandbox link shared, looks like it's working fine. So What exactly do you mean by *I'm stuck on the problem of passing my state to functions outside of a class*? What you are actually looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the state of the Counter class into the alert.js and scorealert,js functions